# Why is my Kendo AutoComplete widget not binding to a JSON object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I have the following code in an MVC controller:

```
public JsonResult ARequest()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> AnObject = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    AnObject["foo"] = new object[] {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
    return Json(AnObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And it works as expected; when I call it from a browser, I get the following JSON object:

```
{"foo":["item 1","item 2","item 3"]}
```

I have another file, this time with a Kendo UI Autocomplete Widget. Here is the code:

```
<input id="products" style="width: 250px" />

/*...*/

$("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
   filter: "contains",
   minLength: 3,
   dataTextField: foo,
   dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      pageSize: 10,
      transport: {
         read: {
            url: "education-portal/ARequest"
         }
      }
   }
});
```

As per the official examples [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/autocomplete/overview#using-the-kendo-ui-web-datasource-component-to-bind-to) and [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/index.html).

The problem is, when I load the page I don't get anything. The AutoComplete is blank and it stays blank. No results show up when I type anything in the box. Any idea what went wrong? I can't see it for the life of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems:

- You should not define `dataTextField` since your array of value are not objects but `strings`.
- You should say where in the received data is actually the array of items.
- Is the `type` *odata* or JSON?

It should be something like:

```
$("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
    filter: "contains",
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        pageSize: 10,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "education-portal/ARequest"
            },
            schema : {
                data: "foo"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rSjpS/

Comment: Can you give me an example of when I might define dataTextField?

Comment: Of course, let assume that your JSON looks like `{"foo":[ { "id": 1, "bar": "item 1"} , { "id": 2, "bar": "item 2"},{ "id": 3, "bar": "item 3"}]}` here you should define `dataTextField: "bar"`. You have an array of objects (instead of strings as in your JSON) and the text elements are set in "bar" in this example you might also set `dataValueField : "id"` then the stored value would be 1, 2,... instead of `item1`, `item2`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are wrapping the collection inside a field called foo, you should specify this via the **dataSource.schema.data** options.

e.g.

```
 dataSource: {
      schema: {
          data: "foo"
      }
 }
```

You do not have to specify any datavaluefield or datatextfield